# Confusing limit questions.

Tags: limits

I've been studying limits and stumbled across two problems I'm stumped on. Could anyone help out with either one or both of these? Would be greatly appreciated. 
$$\lim_{x \to 5^+}  \frac{e^x}{(5-x)^5}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 10^+} \ln (100 - x^2)$$

(Hope I did the text thing right. This is my first post on this site :/ )

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1. ~\lim_{x \to 5^+}  \frac{e^x}{(5-x)^5} = \frac{\to e^5}{ \to 0^-}\longrightarrow \boxed{-\infty}$$

$$2. ~\lim_{x \to 10^+} \ln (100 - x^2) =\ln (\to 0^-) = \boxed{\text{Not defined!}} $$

(Since domain of $\ln (x)$ is $x>0$)